# Beginner issues with python script output

Tags: python, output

The below Python code isn't acting as intended.

The final output is missing all lines that I'd expect to be outputted where `output_data[1] == "S"`.

It also appears my lazy attempt to obfuscate client ID is failing.

```
import csv

TID = 0
ACCT_TYPE = 1
PRODUCT_TYPE = 2
NUM_ACCT_OWNERS = 3
NUM_ACCT = 4
COMBINED_BALANCES = 5
TID_BALANCES = 6
INSURED_BALANCES = 7
ESTIMATED_UNINSURED = 8
FOREIGN_IND = 9

#output_data = [None] * 10

header_row_processed = False

with open("U:\exampletext.txt", 'r') as csvfile:
CIN = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter="\t")
file_output_data = []
for row in CIN:

    if not header_row_processed:
        header_row_processed = True
        continue

    if not row[ACCT_TYPE] == "I" or row[ACCT_TYPE] == "S":
         continue

    if not row[PRODUCT_TYPE] == "Total":
         continue

    output_data = [None] * 6

    client_id = row[TID]
    client_id.replace("0", "x")
    client_id.replace("1", "d")
    client_id.replace("2", "h")
    client_id.replace("3", "g")
    client_id.replace("4", "v")
    client_id.replace("5", "n")
    client_id.replace("6", "m")
    client_id.replace("7", "q")
    client_id.replace("8", "w")
    client_id.replace("9", "r")
    client_id.replace("-", "u")
    output_data[0] = client_id

    output_data[1] = row[ACCT_TYPE]

    output_data[2] = row[PRODUCT_TYPE]

    output_data[3] = row[COMBINED_BALANCES]

    output_data[4] = str(min(float(row[COMBINED_BALANCES])/float(row[NUM_ACCT_OWNERS]), 250000*float(row[NUM_ACCT_OWNERS])))

    output_data[5] = str(max(0, (float(row[COMBINED_BALANCES])/float(row[NUM_ACCT_OWNERS]))-(250000*float(row[NUM_ACCT_OWNERS])))*(float(row[NUM_ACCT_OWNERS])))

    file_output_data.append("\t".join(output_data))

    #file_output_data = ','.join(str(v) for v in value_list)

    if output_data[1] == "I":
        out_file = open(
        'U:\path_one.txt', 'w')
        out_file.write("\n".join(file_output_data))
        out_file.close()

    if output_data[1] == "S":
        out_file = open(
        'U:\path_two.txt', 'w')
        out_file.write("\n".join(file_output_data))
        out_file.close()
```

Comment: You're `continue`s don't seem like they're indented.

Comment: Could you show us the expected output and the real output?

Comment: That is a terrible problem description. Can you reduce the code to a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and correct the indentation? What were you expecting, and what do you see instead? What does *"failing*" mean, exactly?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I would reduce, but I'm unsure where the error is. Indentation corrected. By failing, I mean that it appears to be outputting the original string without any changes. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Brandon The basic idea is that you reduce your code and then look at which step the error disappears. That gives you an idea about the nature of the error. Then if you still don't understand what's wrong you can ask a question that targets the issue.

Comment: Did you mean `if not (row[ACCT_TYPE] == "I" or row[ACCT_TYPE] == "S"):`?

Comment: Another tip would be to avoid doing everything in a long function. You can write a transform_client_id() function for those 10 client_id.replace(). This allows you to test that function independently from the rest of your code and it makes your code more readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is in the part:

```
client_id = row[TID]
client_id.replace("0", "x")
client_id.replace("1", "d")
client_id.replace("2", "h")
client_id.replace("3", "g")
client_id.replace("4", "v")
client_id.replace("5", "n")
client_id.replace("6", "m")
client_id.replace("7", "q")
client_id.replace("8", "w")
client_id.replace("9", "r")
client_id.replace("-", "u")
output_data[0] = client_id
```

Go write an unit test for it and see what the code does. replace doesn't do what you think it does.